# Firebase http function not redirecting to auth page

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an http function that only certain users can access but for some reason the Google Sign In page is not showing when trying to access this function via browser.

I can see there is a CORS error in the console:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://uc.appengine.google.com/_ah/loginform?state=~AJKiYcF8K-nwxdM2Ubrwye8NlIUqgRXpZaYPWgXWmuQz8GuLLMz0Pp24ZZbQLv-OQos-CqD9gYdCIaQXHV7LZ0Ub1NlIxiZuOhORLsEFD_3HPKaTDdNzsX8WJVon09WhyybHJTZmcH2jmcnCNBf7WcsJ7V73NnbEYOSqeWLpINZa4nRbrqTg3HEr-QLMwUjL3VIrkmTxKCK4MJYdUUKaqunIcSBjDnKbnLC58rkwaHiYqcpiMYWPfpp1jfGU_1civWIyIuf4K_4k4Pq0ixm4IUpQfLcxYI928sXMTdhhGT8aDQr5BndoyBfWctnIUeKUlg9FQJIAXX5Ywx6ETfMQgG4PmUQNtbZ0SQ with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Here is the function code:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.get('/all-users', async (request, response) => {    
    const dbRef = admin.database();
    const usersSnapshot = await dbRef.ref('/Users/').once('value');
    const fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'ethnicity', 'otherEthnicity', 'dob', 'gender', 'email', 'friendCode'];
    const options = { fields };

    const report = [];
    usersSnapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
        const user = userSnapshot.val();
        report.push(user);
    });
    const csv = parse(report, options);
    const date = moment().tz(timezone).startOf('day').format('DDMMYYYY').toString();
    response.setHeader(
        "Content-disposition",
        `attachment; filename=UserReport-${date}.csv`
    );
    response.set("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    return response.status(200).send(csv);
});
```

Here is the network tab:
[image: Network Tab]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? The function works fine if it is set as public.

Comment: Have updated the question to include the function code and network tab screenshot

Answer (score 0):

As per this documentation [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768):

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) is an algorithm that can identify and block dubious cross-origin resource loads in web browsers before they reach the web page. CORB reduces the risk of leaking sensitive data by keeping it further from cross-origin web pages.

The [Chromium Developers](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers), which are the developers of this feature, indicates that this error usually doesn't affect the websites, however, in case there is, you can use this below code, to initiate your Chrome to try it:

```
--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating
```

In cases it's indeed confirmed, they recommend you to raise a [Chromium Bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry?template=Defect+report+from+user&components=Internals%3ESandbox%3ESiteIsolation) with them, so they can check it.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Running Chrome with those features disabled does not help, although the console error has gone, so I guess something else is going on.

Comment: Hi @Pedro could you please click in the error `403` from your screenshot and check the exact stacktrace that it's shown in the console?

Comment: that doesn't really give me any details unfortunately.

Comment: If clicking in the error doesn't provide any further details, I would recommend you to reach out to the [Chromium Developers](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers), since they are the developers of this feature and should be able to provide you further feedback.